# Jquery registering a click on an element that was not clicked strange behavior

Tags: jquery, click, live

Given the following html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img rel="20110914103319-9589184176" src="images/redXblackBackground.png" style="float: left;">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following code to register an even when the row is clicked.

```
$('tr').live('click',function(e){
    var tagType = $(this).get(0).tagName;
    console.log(tagType);
});
```

And I have the following code to tell  when the image is click on.

```
$("td img").live('click',function(e){
    opId = $(this).attr('rel');
    console.log(opId);
});
```

The issue is that when I click on the image, it registers that I click on the `tr` element.  I thought perhaps it had to do with the order that the two click block of code were ordered but it made no difference.  I am failing to see why the click on the image would register a click on the `tr` element and not on the `img` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the event propagates up the DOM tree, triggering your other event. Stop it from propagating and your code should work:

```
$("td img").live('click',function(e){
    opId = $(this).attr('rel');
    console.log(opId);

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
My answer used the .click jquery function whereas your question used .live so maybe my answer isn't as relevant as Blender's.

---

Because the img tag is inside the tr tags it is falling through to the click function on its parent tr.

The only way around this that I have ever used is to return false; after all of your required javascript has been completed.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('tr').click(function() {
            alert('tr');
        });

        $('tr span').click(function() {
            alert('span');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<table width="100%">
    <tr style="background: #ccc;">
        <td>
            <span id="test">Test</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Perhaps there is a better way around this but that is how I do it because I don't usually need click events to return a true of false value anyway.

Comment: I understand what you are doing but it does not work for some reason.  I dont even understand why I am forced to use the live event.  I cannot register a click on the `tr` without it.  It is an element that is there when the dom completes so that makes no sense either.